# Discrete symmetries of Hamiltonian and Change of Representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, symmetry, mathematical-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

In quantum mechanics, one could write Hamiltonians for a given quantum system both in coordinate and momentum spaces as mentioned for example in Sakurai book. Does the discrete symmetries such as parity and time reversal symmetry of a given Hamiltonian changes when we change from coordinate representation and vice-versa or they are global properties of the system and are not affected by unitary transformations such as changing the representation.

Comment: Changing representations leaves every measureable effect unchanged, so long as you remember to change the representation for both your states and your observables

Comment: [Time reversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry#Time_reversal_in_quantum_mechanics) doesn't much care about x and p, so switching representation should make no difference to it. Parity inverts coordinates and momenta, and preserves Born's commutation relation. So, both T and P do not care about representation.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks a lot for your great remark. I also expected this. However, due to  hundreds of papers on pt symmetry and breaking of it I just wanted to verify this

Comment: Sure. You *do* know that $P=\int dx~~ |-x\rangle \langle x| = \int dp~~ |-p\rangle \langle p|$, no?